# How to import a Microsoft Word document into Mathematica?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, pdf-format, office

I have a *Microsoft Word* document in DOCX format. I need to import it into *Mathematica* as a `String` preserving all formatting (font, size, bold/italic style, colors, etc), tables and embedded images with highest possible fidelity (*Mathematica* strings support formatting and arbitrary embedded expressions including images). All text should remain editable, so it should not be converted to an image. Is there a way to do this?

I can convert the document to RTF, PDF, XPS, MHT or ODT format before importing, if it helps.

Comment: RTF would be a likely candidate - but what have you tried so far?

Comment: There is one plugin about MathType and Word Called Word2Tex, maybe also helpful for formulas.

Comment: I DID it 6 months after you asked, see here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65687/1056

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David Carlisle wrote about it back in 2007. The process seems to be rather cumbersome and I have not checked myself if it is reliable working but here are some links that might help you on your specific problem:

[XHTML and MathML from Office 2007](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.de/2007/04/xhtml-and-mathml-from-office-20007.html)

[Going Wordless at the Advanced Mathematica Summer School](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/07/31/going-wordless-at-the-advanced-mathematica-summer-school/)

Comment: Hi Stefan, can you show me a little about how to obtain the formulas in Word(maybe Mathtype form) in Notebook? I've tried a little, and Import .xml file(obtain form word) to Notebook.

Comment: @HyperGroups sorry about my late answer. Embarrassingly no :(. I have no windows and on my mac I do have (astonishingly) Word 2011, but the equation editor is different from the windows version. I've tried it out, but the equations are immediately converted into jpg after exporting...sorry about that. I only had those links and posted them as an answer (concealing the fact, that I'm hopelessly clueless about any Office related question; failing even using these applications)

Comment: I DID it 6 months after it was asked, see here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65687/1056

Answer (score 5):

As of 14.0, Import of DOCX file is supported:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/DOCX.html

But the functionality doesn't fully meet your requirement i.e. "import it into *Mathematica* as a `String` preserving all formatting (font, size, bold/italic style, colors, etc), **tables and embedded images**" at least for now. Please check the examples in the document for more info.